# I want to invoke C# script in my aspx webpage, help me implement it

Tags: c#, asp.net, invocation

I want to invoke a C# code into my aspx webpage. Can someone please show me how to do this? C# code is very long, I saved it in a `.cs` file and put it into the web directory along with the web page files, but when I try calling it into my webpage, some server error happens on the page.

Here is the code, kindly help me implement it properly.

Thanks

```
<%@ language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
        string vservADRequest(string vservMsisdn, string vservMarkup, string vservZoneid, bool vservTestMode){
        try{
            StringBuilder vservParams = new StringBuilder();
            vservParams.Append("vr").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode("1.1.0-csharp-20100726")).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("tm").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(vservTestMode.ToString())).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("ml").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(vservMarkup)).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("si").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Session.SessionID)).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("mo").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(vservMsisdn)).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("ip").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.UserHostAddress)).Append("&");

            if(Request.Headers.GetValues("x-forwarded-for") != null)
                vservParams.Append("ff").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers["x-forwarded-for"])).Append("&");

            if(Request.Headers.GetValues("via") != null)
                vservParams.Append("hv").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers["via"])).Append("&");

            vservParams.Append("ht").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers["host"])).Append("&");
            vservParams.Append("ru").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Path)).Append("&");                
            vservParams.Append("ua").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.UserAgent)).Append("&");

            if(Request.Headers.GetValues("x-operamini-phone-ua") != null)
                vservParams.Append("ou").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers["x-operamini-phone-ua"])).Append("&");

            if(Request.Headers.GetValues("x-wap-profile") != null)
                vservParams.Append("up").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers["x-wap-profile"])).Append("&");

            ArrayList vservNotToLog = ArrayList.Adapter(new String[] { "PRAGMA", "CACHE-CONTROL", "CONNECTION", "KEEP-ALIVE"});
            foreach (string vservHeaderName in Request.Headers){
              if (!vservNotToLog.Contains(vservHeaderName.ToUpper())){
                vservParams.Append(Server.UrlEncode("hd["+vservHeaderName+"]")).Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(Request.Headers[vservHeaderName])).Append("&");
                }
            }
            vservParams.Append("zoneid").Append("=").Append(Server.UrlEncode(vservZoneid));
            ASCIIEncoding vservAscii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] vservPostBytes = vservAscii.GetBytes(vservParams.ToString());
            string vservAdUrl= "http://rq.vserv.mobi/delivery/adapi.php?"+vservZoneid;
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest vservReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(vservAdUrl);       
            if (vservReq != null){
                vservReq.Method = "POST";
                vservReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                vservReq.ContentLength = vservPostBytes.Length;
                vservReq.Timeout = 7000;
                if(Context.Items["X-VSERV-CONTEXT"]!=null && !Context.Items["X-VSERV-CONTEXT"].ToString().Equals("")){
                    vservReq.Headers.Add("X-VSERV-CONTEXT", Context.Items["X-VSERV-CONTEXT"].ToString());
                }
                // add post data to request
                System.IO.Stream vservPostStream = vservReq.GetRequestStream();
                vservPostStream.Write(vservPostBytes, 0, vservPostBytes.Length);
                vservPostStream.Close();
                System.Net.HttpWebResponse vservRes = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse) vservReq.GetResponse();
                string newVservContext=vservRes.GetResponseHeader("X-VSERV-CONTEXT");
                Context.Items.Remove("X-VSERV-CONTEXT");
                Context.Items.Add("X-VSERV-CONTEXT",newVservContext);
                System.IO.StreamReader vservSR = new System.IO.StreamReader(vservRes.GetResponseStream());
                StringBuilder vservOutput = new StringBuilder();
                vservOutput.Append(vservSR.ReadToEnd().Trim());
                vservSR.Close();
                return vservOutput.ToString();
            }else{return ""; }

            }catch (Exception vserve) { return "";}
    }
    </script>
    <%
```

Comment: It would help immensely if you would describe the error you are getting.

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET on your computer?

Comment: well error details are not enabled on webpage but it shows some runtime error, i am running IIS7 with all necessary programs. can you tell me how to implement this script properly showing example code? i simply read it from forums to implement this code, i know nothing except implement javascripts.

Comment: What error do you get if you display the exception? You should have some information as how to enable it on your page (adding a `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your web.config). I think if you view the page on localhost you should see errors though

Comment: listen, i removed the install code, i have the code in .cs file in web directory. i used this call code, you can correct this one if this is wrong.

Comment: <%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" runat="server" CodeFile="~/somecode.cs" %>

Comment: is the above code correct????

Comment: @YasirMehmoodButt: "Is the above code correct?" What is it supposed to do? It could have bugs in it but we don't know the logic do we? As per the exception you are getting, unless you specify that, nobody can help you.

Comment: @YasirMehmoodButt: Have you tried debugging to see what exception you're thrown?

Answer (score 0):

If you want invoke method in your aspx, you can use `<% %>` symbol.

```
<% =vservADRequest("test", "test", "test", true) %>
```